# Why my typescript is not allowing to define Tuple Types

Tags: typescript, tuples

[image]

I tried to define tuple type here and it throws an error. Do I need to set any configurations in my nodejs application to accept tuple types?

Comment: looks like you're trying to create a object with a array?

Comment: You need to get familiar with JS Objects in Arrays.

Comment: It is either `color: { red: number; green: number; blue: number }` or `color: [number, number, number]`

Answer (score 0):

There are some other errors with your syntax but I see that you're trying to give a name to your tuple.

```js
type color = [red: number, green: number, blue: number]
```

The error you're seeing is the type `Spectra` cannot be defined in that manner. Alternatives are:

```js
type Spectra = [
  [red: number, green: number, blue: number]
]

// or

interface Spectra {
  color: [red: number, green: number, blue: number]
}
```